# ASP.NET Core ServiceCollection

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to understand **ServiceCollection**.
Could please someone explain ServiceCollection is?

```
public void ConfigureServices(**IServiceCollection** services)
{
    **services**.AddMvc();
}
```

Comment: In other words, you are asking for a *tutorial* on Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core. Did you try the tutorial in the documentation site at  [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1)? That tutorial is the first result if you google for `ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection`

Comment: Can you be more specific? *What* did you not understand?

Comment: You can also try MSDN Magazine's [Essential .NET - Dependency Injection with .NET Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707534.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). This explains how Dependency Injection works for any .NET Core application, not just ASP.NET Core